# uncover cells in siunitx table beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, siunitx

I wish to show a calculation and update a table to help keep track of things. I use `siunitx` and `booktabs` in my beamer presentation. I want to have the numbers in the table aligned on the decimal point, which I can do no problem. However, I want to uncover data in the table as I go along. There seems to be a problem with using `siunitx`.

MWE showing static table...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{exampleblock}{Step 6 --- What is the Empirical formula?}
Get smallest whole number ratio of moles
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]}
\toprule
            &{C}        &{H}            &{O}    & {Totals}\\
\midrule
moles (\num{d-4})   &1.417  & 4.25      &0  &0\\
ratio ($\div $ 1.417)   & 1 &2.99       &0  &0  \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Empirical Formula is \ch{CH3}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now if I try to uncover the values in the table...

MWE...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{exampleblock}{Step 6 --- What is the Empirical formula?}
Get smallest whole number ratio of moles
\onslide<2->{\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]}
\toprule
            &{C}        &{H}            &{O}    & {Totals}\\
\midrule
\onslide<3->{moles (\num{d-4})} & {\onslide<3->{1.417}} &  {\onslide<3->{4.25}}     & {\onslide<3->{0}} & {\onslide<3->{0}}\\
{\onslide<4->{ratio ($\div $ 1.417)}}   & {\onslide<5->{1}  }& {\onslide<5->{2.99}}     &{\onslide<3->{0}}  &{\onslide<3->{0}}  \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\onslide<6->{Empirical Formula is \ch{CH3}}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I lose the alignment on the decimal point as enclosing the `\onslide<+->{...}` in `{` and `}` treats the value as text and does not align it. If I do not enclose in parentheses I get an error saying `too many $'s or extra}`

Now I'm not too bothered about the alignment but if it could be done I would be grateful. I doubt the students would see the misalignment (probably querying why they decided to study chemistry...;>)